# Works fine on localhost, but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a problem on heroku, when I try to access my posts. The logs says:

```
Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (920.6ms)
2015-11-06T09:39:41.716328+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 936ms (ActiveRecord: 42.1ms)
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720223+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720226+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass):
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720227+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:            <dt> <%= post.body %> </dt>
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720227+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:             <dd><%= post.tags %> </dd>
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720228+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:          </dl>
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720229+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:          <%= gravatar_for post.user, size: 40%> Created by <b><%= post.user.name if post.user %></b>
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720229+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:         </td>
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720230+00:00 app[web.1]:     27: 
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720231+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:     <div>
2015-11-06T09:39:41.720231+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/users_helper.rb:3:in `gravatar_for'
```

On `localhos:3000/posts` it works good, the mistake appears only on heroku. 
I use PostgreSQL both in development and production.

Here is my routes.rb:

```
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :posts
 root 'posts#index'
   match '/signup', to: 'users#new',         via: 'get'
   match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new',      via: 'get'
   match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
```

A part of my posts#index:

```
<div class="show_posts">
<table>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>

        <td>
         <dl> <%= post.title %>
           <dt> <%= post.body %> </dt>
            <dd><%= post.tags %> </dd>
         </dl>
         <%= gravatar_for post.user, size: 40%> Created by <b><%= post.user.name if post.user %></b>
        </td>
```

users_helper.rb:

```
module UsersHelper
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Your `post` doesn't have associated `User` record.

Comment: first check that your @user should be not nil ??

Comment: I have a `belongs_to :user` in Post model, and a `has_many :posts` in User model

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi but you don't have actual `User` record associated with at least one of your `Post` records.

Comment: Then why does it works locally?

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi because you have different DB locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies inside `gravatar_for`, where you call...

```
Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
```

The required `user` object doesn't exist.

This is *caused* in your `posts#index` model, when you reference:

```
<%= gravatar_for post.user, size: 40%> Created by <b><%= post.user.name if post.user %>
```

---

As suggested in the comments, this is likely due to you not having an associated `user` object for your `post`.

The immediate fix will be to use some conditional logic to determine whether the `user` exists (which you're doing already, but only for the `post.user.name` output):

```
<% if post.user %>
    <%= gravatar_for post.user, size: 40 %> Created by <b><%= post.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, you may wish to make all posts have a user by using  a validation to determine whether the associated object is set:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts, inverse_of: :user
end

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :posts
   validates :user, present: true
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Doing:   `<% if post.user %>
        <%= gravatar_for post.user, size: 40 %> Created by <b><%= post.user.name %>
    <% end %>` solved the issue.